# How to restrict access to programs on stand-alone rds Windows 2012 Server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, remote, remote-desktop-services

I'm running a VPS with Windows 2012 Server placed at a hosting company so it's not connected to a domain.

How can I restrict access to programs for the remote desktop users with this setup? Since the server is not connected to a domain it's not possible to configure RemoteApp through the server manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a Non-Administrators local Group Policy and use Software Restrictions to prevent Non-Administrators from running all programs except the ones that you specify.